# Is the visible mannequin in the opening car bomb scene in Casino (1995) intentional, and if so why?

Tags: effects, casino

In the opening scene of *[Casino](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112641/?ref_=nv_sr_2)* (1995), **Sam Rothstein** gets into his car and is blown up. In the moment of the detonation, you can *clearly* see that **DeNiro** has been replaced with a dummy. (When the scene is repeated near the end of the film, there is no dummy).

While some could claim that this was just a bad cut, to anyone who knows **Scorsese**, this seems highly unlikely. Watch any interview of him and you will see his attention to every detail. He even likes putting in subtle references to films he loved as a boy. In at least one death scene in *[The Departed](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0407887/?ref_=nv_sr_1)* (2006), the actor involved passes crosses made with tape on windows in an abandoned building, a clear reference to *[Scarface](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0023427/?ref_=nv_sr_2)* (1932), in which [crosses (or X-es) always appear in the background of a scene (either in the prop construction or caused by light falling on the background) when someone is about to die](https://m00ch.wordpress.com/2010/10/10/scarface-1932-and-its-x-motif/). There are copious examples of this kind of care with detail from Marty. A mistake seems unlikely.

Also, with *Casino*, **Scorsese** had one of the largest budgets that he's worked ([$40-50 million](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casino_(film))) with so a lack of money for good effects seems unlikely too.

**Q: Has it been revealed anywhere why Martin Scorcese used this scene which APPEARS to be a sub-par effects shot (the dummy) in the film ?**

*Any answer that can reference Marty himself will of course trump all others. I'm not really after conjecture - I can do that myself.*

Comment: You wanted him to actually kill Deniro?

Comment: I think that's against SAG rules

Comment: Honestly, it likely had to do with the scene being an expensive practical effect shot, and the problem wasn't visible until editing, where the cost of a reshoot or expensive CGI would have been out of the question for a few frames.

Comment: @cde I re-edited the post. I am looking for more than conjecture at this point.

Comment: The comment section is for conjecture :) your title needs work though

Comment: I have a theory that perhaps because Sam wasn't really blown up, that it was a visual cue to the artifice of the opening scene (which is revealed later when we see the *real* explosion). I mean, after the explosion, Sam is flying and cartwheeling around in a short fantasy scene. I've *heard* Marty talk about minute details he's included to make a point, and my feeling is he may have done that here, but I don't know. I'm hoping someone may have heard or seen something definitive.

Comment: Trying to stay focussed. I'm waiting to see if anyone has heard anything legit. If I put my theory up there, my brain tumor will kill me while I read through the waterfall of conjecture that may appear down here.

Comment: scene here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcf8C3AWjxk

Comment: That makes no sense if you know MS.

Comment: I changed the title again because it became a question I didn't ask.